# How do you solve the equation $ (z^2-1)^2 = 4 ? $

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

$ (z^2-1)^2 = 4  \iff $$z_1 = 3 $ and $ z_2=-1$

$arg(z_1)= 0 ,  arg(z_2) = \pi$

$$ z_1 = \sqrt{3} \left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2}\right)\right)$$

$$z_2 = i \left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2} +\pi\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi k}{2} +\pi\right)\right) \mid k= \{ 0,1 \}$$

$$ z = \{ \sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}, i, -i \}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You mean $z_1^2=3$ and so on

Comment: Yes, it seems right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(z^2-1)^2=4\iff$

$z^2-1=2,-2\iff$

$z^2=3,-1\iff$

$z=\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{-1},-\sqrt{-1}\iff$

$z=\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},i,-i$

Comment: This is nice and simple. I hardly can believe this is "legal". Can you really handle complex powers like with real-numbers??

Comment: @user1511417: Yes.

Comment: Caveat: When you take the $n$th root of both sides, you will have $n$ solutions, some of which you will have ignored with real numbers.

Comment: @GFauxPas: True, but in the case above I have not ignored any such solution.

Comment: @GFauxPas: Computing the $n$th root yields $n$ solutions. Here, we have $n=2$, hence $2$ solutions. If it was a different case, then I would use a more general method in order to compute all $n$ solutions.

Comment: It was just a warning to "can you really handle...," question, not a critique of your answer.

Comment: @GFauxPas: Oh, I understand now. Good point, thanks :)

Comment: And a "more general method" would be with sin/cos for example (like above) ?

Comment: @user1511417 Google "roots of unity". Have fun! I recommend the (e-)book by Brown and Churchill

Answer (score 2):

$(z^2-1)^2=4\Leftrightarrow (z^2-1)^2-2^2=0\Leftrightarrow (z^2-1-2)(z^2-1+2)=0\Leftrightarrow(z^2-3)(z^2+1)=0\Leftrightarrow (z-\sqrt 3)(z+\sqrt 3)(z-i)(z+i)=0$
It follows that $z\in\{\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 3, i,-i\}$
.